# MySQL connector EF stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSequenceNextValue(IN sequenceName VarChar(100))
BEGIN
  UPDATE Sequences Set currentValue = LAST_INSERT_ID(CurrentValue + 1) WHERE name = sequenceName
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

But when I update my model, this procedure is not imported even into storage model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have performed a test, this procedure is added correctly using [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/). 
You can download the Trial edition and have full functionality during 30 days evaluation period.

Comment: I have already downloaded your provider and it really imported this stored procedure. But unfortunately I can't work with my remote MySQL database using your provider: I get connection lost error (reported to your form).